# Return a specific/200 status code for a particular URL prefix in Haproxy

Tags: linux, haproxy

In Nginx we can return a specific status code to URL prefix like this.

`location /api {
    return 200;
 }`

How can we achieve the same in Haproxy?.

Gone through Haproxy ACL but couldn't find any.

Comment: The requirement is not clear, returning a code status is a web server feature rather than a reverse proxy one. HAProxy is not a web server.
Are you using HAProxy as reverse proxy / load balancer ? and you want to override a backend response ?

Comment: yes, want to override the backend response by ignoring the URI prefix or giving a 200 status code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using a lua response script.
I already use one to set the CORS headers for the preflight response.

My rule is the following:

```
global
    ...
    lua-load /etc/haproxy/200.lua

frontend
    bind ...
    ...
    use_backend http_200 if ...

backend http_200
    http-request use-service lua.200-response
```

Lua script in `/etc/haproxy/200.lua`:

```
# 200.lua
core.register_service("200-response", "http", function(applet)
    local response = ""
    applet:set_status(200)
    applet:add_header("Content-Length", "0")
    applet:start_response()
    applet:send(response)
end)
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, from version 2.2 you can return dynamic content like this

```
http-request return status 200 content-type "text/plain" lf-string "Hello"
```

More in [docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20return).